# A-Star doesnt behave like it should

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, a-star

I'm quite new to pathfinding and recently got A-Star working for the first time in Java with Libgdx, but it has some flaws, it doesnt always find the fastest path , or the program simply kills itself(because it's too slow?) :/

(Input/Output here: [Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cNVO.jpg): White = untouched Node, green = start, red = target, blue = path, yellow = node is on closed list but unrelevant)

The rest of the code can be found [on Github](https://github.com/Tommyten/libgdx-Game/tree/master/core/src/com/mygdx/game).

This is the code for the Algorithm itself:

> Node lastNode;
>
> Node[] neighborNodes;
>
> int lowestF = 2000;
>
> Node bestNode;

```
public void findPath() {
    for(int x = 0; x < map.worldWidth; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < map.worldHeight; y++) {
            nodes[x][y].calculateHeuristic(targetNode);
        }
    }

    lastNode = startNode;

    while(lastNode != targetNode || !openList.isEmpty()) {
        neighborNodes = map.getNeighbors(lastNode);
        for(Node node:neighborNodes) {
            if(node != null)
                if(node.state != State.BLOCKED && !closedList.contains(node)) {
                    openList.add(node);
                    node.parentNode = lastNode;
                }
        }
        lowestF = 1000;
        for(Node node:openList) {
            if(node.f <= lowestF) {
                lowestF = node.f;
                bestNode = node;
            }
        }
        if(openList.isEmpty() && bestNode != targetNode) {
            System.out.println("No Path possible");
            return;
        }
        openList.remove(bestNode);
        closedList.add(bestNode);
        lastNode = bestNode;
        lastNode.setState(State.SEARCHED);
    }

    reconstructPath();
}

public void reconstructPath() {
    Node lastNode = targetNode;
    while(lastNode != startNode) {
        lastNode = lastNode.parentNode;
        lastNode.setState(State.PATH);
    }
    setStartAndEnd();
}
```

And the Node Class:

```
public class Node {

public enum State {
    NORMAL, BLOCKED, START, END, SEARCHED, PATH
}

public State state;
int xPos, yPos;
Color color;
Node parentNode;

int f;
int movementCost = 10;
int heuristic;

public Node(int x, int y) {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    setState(State.NORMAL);
}

public void setState(State newState) {  
    state = newState;
}

public boolean isNodeClicked() {
    int inputX = Gdx.input.getX();
    int inputY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY();
    if(inputX > xPos*32 && inputX < xPos*32+32 && 
        inputY > yPos*32 && inputY < yPos*32+32) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void calculateHeuristic(Node targetNode) {
    heuristic = (Math.abs((xPos-targetNode.xPos)) + Math.abs((yPos-targetNode.yPos))) * movementCost;
    f = movementCost+heuristic;
}

public int calculateHeuristic(Node finishNode, int useless) {
    return (Math.abs((xPos-finishNode.xPos)) + Math.abs((yPos-finishNode.yPos))) * movementCost;
}
```

}

At the moment I'm using a 2-dimensional array for the map or nodes and Arraylist for open and closed list.

It'd be much appreciated if somebody could help me get my A-star to behave and explain to me what I did wrong, I would also be very grateful for any other criticism, since I want to improve my programming :)

Thanks for your help in Advance :)

Comment: Please post your code here. Please post specific inputs and specific outputs and how they differ from what you expect here as well. And you want [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for suggestions on improving your coding style, StackOverflow is only for specific answers to specific programming questions (It's a Q&A site after all).

Comment: @aruisdante yup, actually wanted to do that and forgot it. Here we go again :D

Comment: what does ``reconstructPath()`` do? Why do you iterate over every cell in the map calculating the heuristic value when you only need to know them for the ones that you explore, negating a big savings of A* over Dijkstra's? Why do you continue even if ``openList.isEmpty()`` is ``true``, which would imply there are no more cells to explore? What does your ``Node`` class look like? Even then, we still don't have much to guide us towards what would be causing the problem without seeing an input and output vs. expected output.

Comment: `reconstructPath(`): `public void reconstructPath() {
  Node lastNode = targetNode;
  while(lastNode != startNode) {
   lastNode = lastNode.parentNode;
   lastNode.setState(State.PATH);
  }
  setStartAndEnd();
 }`

I didn't actually know that I dont need the heuristic for every Node, and it shouldnt continue if `openList.isEmpty()`, that was one of the mistakes I didn't spot so far. Node class I will add to the starting post. Also the I/O is in the Imgur album, since I already used visualization, so I understand it better.

Comment: But thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Please post the images here. That imagur link could die at any moment, and then this question would be useless for potential future visitors. SO Questions/Answers should always be self-contained as much as possible. Also please update that ``reconstructPath()`` into the Question as well ;) And yeah, in A* you only should calculate heuristics for Nodes you're placing onto the open-set.

Comment: I unfortunately can't add Images to my Questions yet, even though I agree with your point :( Also everything very relevant should be in now, the rest of the code can be found in the github link though, since I don't want the post to be too long.

Comment: Your third example is actually also not the shortest path, it should do diagonal lines to the wall-apex.

Comment: I left out diagonals on purpose ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public void calculateHeuristic(Node targetNode) {
    heuristic = (Math.abs((xPos-targetNode.xPos)) + Math.abs((yPos- targetNode.yPos))) * movementCost;
    f = movementCost+heuristic;
}
```

Your calculation of your heuristic is wrong, because your calculation of your `movementCost` is wrong. The cost of a node is not a fixed value. It's the summation of all of the costs to move between nodes along the path to that node so far. So your node should actually have a function,

```
public int calculateCost(){
    if(parentNode != null){
        return movementCost + parentNode.calculateCost();
    } else{
        return movementCost;
    }
}
```

And your heuristic thus becomes:

```
public void calculateHeuristic(Node targetNode) {
    heuristic = (Math.abs((xPos-targetNode.xPos)) + Math.abs((yPos- targetNode.yPos))) * movementCost;
    f = calculateCost()+heuristic;
}
```

Your other problems look like they probably all come from the  various typos/logical errors I mentioned in the comments (`while(...||openSet.isEmpty())` instead of `while(...|| !openSet.isEmpty())`, etc)

Comment: This solved it thank you! :) Thanks for taking the time and pointing out other mistakes :)

Have a nice day! :)